# Cloud Build service account no access to storage.objects.get

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I am trying to get a Google Cloud Functions to print something from a file in a storage bucket.
I have the file stored in a bucket, an authenticated service account with `Storage Admin`, `Cloud Run Admin`, `Service Account User` and `Cloud Functions Admin` and the following python script.

```py
def from_storage(event, context):
    import json
    from google.cloud import storage

    client = storage.Client(project='my-project')
    try:
        bucket = client.get_bucket('my-storage')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Bucket not found.')
        print(e)
    try:
        blob = bucket.blob('Hello_World.json')
        data = json.load(blob.download_as_string())
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error loading file:')
        print(e)
```

I try to deploy this with the following code:

```
gcloud functions deploy from_storage --runtime python39 --triger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

To which I get an error that the deploying service account (which seems to be an automatically created service account), does not have `storage.objects.get` permissions:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: could not resolve storage source: googleapi: Error 403: 488395598433@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden
```

I find this rather strange, as I do not see this service account in my IAM, nor can I access its permissions in Cloud Functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If after re-enabling the Cloud Build API you still don’t see its service account, please add it manually through the “IAM & Admin” -> “IAM” page granting it the Cloud Build Service Account role.

Comment: Re-enabling did the job. I had the Cloud Build API enabled before already, any idea why the corresponding service account didn't appear?

Comment: i got this error too. 20 Apr 2021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the `488395598433@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` - is a Cloud Build service account, where the prefix (number) is the number of the project, where that Cloud Build is running. Can you check that the Cloud Build API is enabled, please? and the Cloud Build service account has relevant permissions, please?

During the runtime, by default, the cloud function is running under `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account, where the `PROJECT_ID` is the ID of the project, where that cloud function is deployed (and should run). This is an App Engine default service account.

It is possible (and recommended) to create a dedicated service accounts according to the principle of least privilege. In that case you might deploy the cloud function with correspondent arguments (not in your example).

From the best of my understanding of your particular example, the default App Engine service account is going to be used.

In either case, the cloud function runtime service account should have relevant privileges (IAM permissions/roles) to work with APIs and resources (in any projects).

Can you check that the cloud function runtime service account has a relevant permissions for accessing the cloud storage bucket, please? Bear in mind that the cloud function might be deployed into one project, and the bucket might be in another project.

In your post you mentioned that you have a "an authenticated service account with" some permissions. What is that service account for, if you deploy your service account with the default App Engine Account? Probably I missed something. "In order to deploy a function with a non-default service account, the deployer must have the `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission on the service account being deployed." - from [Permissions required to use non-default identities](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#permissions_required_to_use_non-default_identities) If that is your case - can you check it as well, please?

Comment: The prefix of the service account that does the deploying is not the project number. The Cloud Build API was enabled, and after re-enabling the deploying service account appeared in IAM. Giving it the appropriate rights allowed me to deploy the function. The function is now indeed run by a different service account, `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: Based on my experience, and an all cases I saw so far, the number prefix in the Cloud Build services account - like `488395598433@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` - I mean the number `488395598433` - is actually the project number where the cloud build service is running. Depending on IAM permisions and GCP projects and APIs configuration, that service account can manage arbitrary resources in arbitrary GCP projects.

Comment: The Cloud Build service account and a Cloud Function run time service account (App Engine default service account in the particular case under discussion) - are completely different service accounts.

Answer (score 3):

If you couldn't see “xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com” listed among other service accounts. Therefore, I believe that something went wrong when activating the Cloud Build API. Could you please disable the Cloud Build API and then enable it again to see if it resolves the issue?

If after re-enabling the Cloud Build API you still don’t see its service account, please add it manually through the “IAM & Admin” -> “IAM” page granting it the Cloud Build Service Account role.

Comment: Same here, couldn't find any trace of the cloud build service account, although the API was enabled. Disabling/re-enabling it fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Refer to:
[Configure Access for Cloud Build Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account) and this [link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-build-service-account) which explains the permissions the automatically created Cloud Build Service Account starts with (granted upon automatic creation).

From my experience and what I guess is going on behind the scenes, I got this error, and you might have too, because you are using the Cloud Build service for the first time. So I got the error on the first run of my script, but **on subsequent runs the error is gone**. This means it takes time for the permissions granting to take place on the servers.

Comment: This worked for me.  Google Cloud Build failed the first time.  But `gcloud app deploy` then succeeded on the subsequent run!